# catch date object for further processing

Tags: java, matlab, return, reusability, return-type

I have written a java code which is called from Matlab environment.The code returns a **DATE** object.I want to use this Date Object for further processing.But How?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.TimeTCPClient;// third party class
import java.util.Date;
public final class TimeClient
{

public static final Date timeTCP(String host) throws IOException
{
TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
try 
{
// We want to timeout if a response takes longer than 4 seconds
client.setDefaultTimeout(4000);
client.connect(host);
Date t=client.getDate();
System.out.println(t);
return t;
}
finally
{
client.disconnect();
}
}


public static final void main(String[]args)
{
{
try
{
timeTCP(args[0]);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(1);
}
}
}
}
```

This is my Matlab code which calls the above java code.I saved it as an M-file

```
function t = gettime()

    import java.io.IOException
    import java.util.Date
    import org.apache.commons.net.TimeTCPClient
    import MATLAB.project.*
     tc= TimeClient 
     tc.main('time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov')
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [DNA mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386476/669202), you should call `timeTCP` directly, and you can throw away your `main` function in Java (as far as Matlab is concerned). Your last MATLAB line needs to be

```
t = tc.timeTCP('time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov')
```

otherwise your MATLAB function only *displays* the date (due to missing semicolon at the end of the line), but your variable `t` remains unset, which will cause a runtime error if anyone calls your function `gettime` explicitly expecting an output, e.g. `variablename = gettime;`.

Comment: thanx Jonas You have come again to rescue me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the Matlab code right, you are calling the `main()` method of `TimeClient`. In Java, `main()` methods have return type `void`, i.e. they don't return anything, so your Matlab code can't get at the time value.

In addition, from `main()` you call `timeTCP()`, which returns a `Date`, but then you don't do anything with the return value, so it would be lost even if `main()` could return it.

You need to call a non-void method that returns a suitable value (and probably assign that value to a variable in Matlab).

**Updated:** Looks like you could just call `timeTCP()` directly, rather than `main()`, because `timeTCP()` does return a `Date`.

I'm not very familiar with MATLAB so unsure whether you need to explicitly return it from `gettime()` or whether that's implied by the last statement.

Comment: @ DNA I am expalining the last line of code in matlab  since main is the method of TCPClient class therefore I have to create an object of class.With the help of that object I am calling its main method and the argument of main method is the address of time server. t variable in matlab code doesn't store any value ,completely useless.

Comment: +1; but the return value is not implied - the last MATLAB line needs to start with t=

Comment: @shree I'm pretty sure you are not creating an instance of TimeClient - you are just calling static (class) methods. As I said, calling main() is no use if you want a return value.